# NSIS: Script compatible with NSIS2 and NSIS3

Tags: nsis

Nsis 3 supports new commands like `Unicode true`. I want a script that works with `makensis2` and `makensis3`. Is this possible? I use linux.

I tried to write a script. But the compiler doens't accept this

**Update:**

```
!if "${NSIS_PACKEDVERSION}" > 0x02ffffff ; NSIS 3+
  Unicode true
  ManifestSupportedOS all
!else
  !warning "NSIS v2, compiling ANSI installer!"
!endif
```

I use this but get still the error message `warning 7070: Invalid number: "${NSIS_PACKEDVERSION}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${If}` is a run-time command but you need to use preprocessor instructions and all of those start with `!`.

```
!if "${NSIS_PACKEDVERSION}" > 0x02ffffff ; NSIS 3+
  Unicode true
!else
  !warning "NSIS v2, compiling ANSI installer!"
!endif
```

This is the official way but might not work with unofficial releases if `VER_PACKED` was not passed to SCons when building MakeNSIS.

Here is something that relies on the improved number parser in NSIS v3 instead:

```
!if 0n1 > 0 ; >= 3.0b0 (Documented in chapter 5.1)
  Unicode true
!else
  !warning "NSIS v2, compiling ANSI installer!"
!endif
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work with ``nsis3``. I get the warning ``warning 7070: Invalid number: "${NSIS_PACKEDVERSION}"``. Any idea?

Comment: Same for me, I'm using MakeNSIS v3.03 on macOS 10.13

Comment: You are not setting the VER_PACKED scons parameter when compiling?

Comment: Are the scons paramaters used for the official distribution documented somewhere? I'm using [similar parameters](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/makensis.rb#L49-L52) as those specified as in kichik's [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/kichik/nsis/blob/master/.travis.yml#L17)

Comment: Thanks. The second solution works. Could you explain better, what the problem is, please? I want to create a bug report for the nsis package for ubuntu.

Comment: `VER_PACKED=0x######` was not set when compiling. I'll see if we can do better on our end, either by parsing the other version number (if specified) or give a warning.

Comment: NSIS_PACKEDVERSION should now be set automatically in 3.04+ even if you don't specify VER_PACKED when building.